# Laravel: How to determine the type of owners of a many to many polymorphic relation?

Tags: laravel-5, polymorphism, many-to-many

I follow the [example here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) and made a many to many polymorphic relation. I have:

```
tags:
-PHP
-movie
```

If I run this

```
Route::get('tag/{id}/', function($id){    
  $tag = Tag::find($id);
  return $tag;    
});
```

The website will give me this

```
{"id":2,"name":"movie","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

If I lucky or I know for sure that this tag belongs to a post, when I use

```
return $tag->posts;
```

It will return me the array with info of the post. But how can I determine the type of owner (post or video) that the tag belongs to so I can use appropriate functions(like posts or videos)?
In the one to many polymorphic relation example, I can look at imageable_type to know which type of owner(order, staff) I'm dealing with. But I can't retrieve taggable_type in many to many polymorphic. I tried

```
Route::get('tag/{id}/', function($id){    
    $tag = Tag::find($id);
    return $tag->taggable;
});
```

but nothing happened. How can I retrieve this attribute? I'm using Laravel 5.2.39.

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `instanceof`

**EDIT** I might have misread it - but I'm not entirely sure. If you want to know *which* owner to call, determine what kind of model is being returned (using, for example, instanceof) and then call the correct `belongsTo` method defined in that model.

```
use App\Post;
use App\Video;

if($tag instanceof Post) {
    // Do something
} elseif($tag instanceof Video) {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: I followed your solution, but the $tag doesn't match any of condition above(instanceof Post or Video). It shows array of info when I use echo $tag->posts; so the tag does belong to a post. Back to my problem, to retrieve the owner of a tag, I have to use "posts" or "videos" functions, so I have to know what type of "thing"(I don't know how to say this, a word to represent a post or a video in general for this case) belongs to(Post or Video). I want to retrieve the type to store that type info and use it in switch to determine how to treat the tag owner. Hope you understand what I say.

Comment: I want to know whether the tag owner is a post or a video to use function posts or videos to retrieve the owner. I want to take this information and store it in a variable for switch argument, which has case : "App\Post" and case: "App\Video".